# Why is our universe the smallest kind in existence?

Tags: scripture, gods, philosophy, brahma

I read that our universe is the smallest kind, because the Brahma in this universe only has four heads, while in larger universes Brahma has for example, a million heads.

Why does a universe kind depend on how many heads its Brahma has?

Comment: You need to give a better source for this other than 'you read'. Where did you read this?